# Using VBA to submit a javascript form

Tags: javascript, forms, vba

I am writing a program to fill in a form on a webpage and then submit it. However, I can't get the form to submit.

I have included a link to the [website](https://www.yourwealth.co.uk/insurance/life-insurance-quotes#117e8786/).

The button is called 'Get Instant Quotes' but I can't seem to be able to reference it at all.

My code so far

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
'Determine Number of Quotes
If Range("Start").Offset(2, 0) = "" Then
    TotalQuotes = 1
Else
    TotalQuotes = Range("Start").End(xlDown).Row - 4
End If
i = 4
T = i - 3
Application.StatusBar = "Getting Quote " & T & " out of " & TotalQuotes
Do Until Worksheets("Front").Cells(i, 1) = ""
Website = Worksheets("Front").Range("A1")
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate Website

IE.Visible = True

While IE.Busy
   DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
Wend
While IE.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend
'Type of Product
'Life Only
Worksheets("Front").Select
If Mid(Cells(i, 2), 2, 1) = "T" Then
    CIC_IND = 0
    CIC_Type = "guaranteed"
Else
    CIC_IND = 1
    CIC_Type = Cells(i, 7)
    If CIC_Type = "G" Then
        CIC_Type = "guaranteed"
    Else
        CIC_Type = "(reviewabl"
    End If
    IE.Document.getElementById("IncludeCriticalIllnessPolicyYes").Click
End If
'Name
IE.Document.getElementById("strFirstName").Value = "Andy Williams"
'Address
IE.Document.getElementById("address").Value = "10 Jones Street"
'City
IE.Document.getElementById("city").Value = "leicester"
'Post Code
IE.Document.getElementById("strPostcode").Value = "LE1 2GH"
'Phone Number
IE.Document.getElementById("strPhoneNumber").Value = "01245337235"
'Email
IE.Document.getElementById("strEmail").Value = "Andy.williams@hotmail.com"
'Single or Joint
If Left(Cells(i, 3), 1) = "J" Then
    IE.Document.getElementById("strData3").Value = "YOU_PARTNER"
Else
    IE.Document.getElementById("strData3").Value = "YOU"
End If
'Level or Decreasing
If Left(Cells(i, 2), 1) = "D" Then
    IE.Document.getElementById("strData4").Value = "MORTGAGE_PROTECTION"
Else
    IE.Document.getElementById("strData4").Value = "PL_COVER"
End If
'Sum Assured
SumAssured = Worksheets("Front").Cells(i, 6)
IE.Document.getElementById("strData2").Value = SumAssured
'Policy Term
Policy_Term = Worksheets("Front").Cells(i, 5)
IE.Document.getElementById("strData5").Value = Policy_Term
'Date of Birth
DOB_Year = Right(Cells(2, 1), 4) - Cells(i, 4)
DOB_Month = Mid(Cells(2, 1), 4, 2)
DOB_Day = Left(Cells(2, 1), 2)
IE.Document.getElementById("strDOBDay").Value = DOB_Day
IE.Document.getElementById("strDOBMonth").Value = DOB_Month
IE.Document.getElementById("strDOBYear").Value = DOB_Year
'Gender
IE.Document.getElementById("strGender").Value = "MALE"
'Smoker Status
If Right(Cells(i, 3), 1) = "M" Then
    IE.Document.getElementById("StrSmoker").Value = "YES"
Else
    IE.Document.getElementById("StrSmoker").Value = "NO"
End If
'If Left(Cells(i, 3), 1) = "J" Then
 '   Joint_Ind = 1
  '  IE.document.GetElementById("SecondApplicantTitle").Value = "2"
   ' IE.document.GetElementById("SecondApplicantForename").Value = "Andrea"
    'IE.document.GetElementById("secondApplicantSurname").Value = "Williams"
    'Date of Birth
    'DOB_Year = Right(Cells(2, 1), 4) - Cells(i, 4)
    'DOB_Month = Mid(Cells(2, 1), 4, 2)
'    DOB_Month = 3
 '   DOB_Day = Left(Cells(2, 1), 2)
  '  DOB = DOB_Day & "/" & DOB_Month & "/" & DOB_Year
   ' IE.document.GetElementById("SecondApplicantDateOfBirth").Value = DOB
    'Smoker Status
    'If Right(Cells(i, 3), 1) = "M" Then
     '   IE.document.GetElementById("SecondApplicantSmokerYes").Click
    'Else
     '   IE.document.GetElementById("SecondApplicantSmokerNo").Click
    'End If
'Else
 '   Joint_Ind = 0
'End If
```

Comment: The sourcecode near the button is div class="row inset">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button orange getQuotes large">Get Instant Quotes</a>

Comment: It also says this in the source code <div class="contactForm quoteForm"> <div class="contactFormInner"> <div class="offer"><img src="/img/from5.png" width="136" height="136" alt="From £5 a month" border="0" /></div> <h3 class="withoffer">Three Step Life Insurance Quote Service</h3>

Answer (score 0):

Since IE supports getELementsByClassName, you can reference the anchor element (Get Instant Quotes) as follows (and should be able to click it - although I haven't tried it):

```
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName('button orange getQuotes large')[0].Click
```

Let me know if this works. If not, I'll setup a test site and we can take it from there.

**EDIT**

Here's a test I setup (using MS-Access 2007 VBA) that merely causes the form to be submitted. Since I have not filled in any fields, the site shows the required fields that are empty. Try it for yourself:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate "https://www.yourwealth.co.uk/insurance/life-insurance-quotes#46870bb5/"
IE.Visible = True
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("button orange getQuotes large")(0).Click
```

**IE8 Solution**

This solution uses getElementsByTagName, which is supported by IE8.

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate "https://www.yourwealth.co.uk/insurance/life-insurance-quotes#46870bb5/"
IE.Visible = True
Dim elems As Object
Set elems = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
Dim elem As Object
For Each elem In elems
  If elem.className = "button orange getQuotes large" Then
    elem.Click
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried this but it didn't like it. It wouldn't let me add the [0] part either. I tried IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("button orange getQuotes large").Click but I get the error message This object doen't support this property or method.

Comment: Did you get an error. Just to be sure it is finding the element, please try: alert(IE.Document.getElementsByClassName('button orange getQuotes large')[0].length) and see if a "1" is displayed.

Comment: Forget my last comment and just replace [0] with (0) and give it another try.

Comment: Hi, I replaced the [0] with (0) but I get the same error message. 'This object doesn't support this property or method'

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a button, but a JavaScript form that needs submitting.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code and still get an error message. Could I have the settings of my VBA wrong? or have an old version of excel?

Comment: What version of VBA are you using (Help | About MS-VB)? Have you tried creating a separate sub/function containing only the code above?

Comment: I am using visual basic 6.3, Excel 2002 and Internet Explorer 8. I think it may be due to an old Internet Explorer. I have tried using the code in a separate sub and get the same error. It works on my home laptop which hsa internet explorer 9 and excel 2007 but not on my work laptop. I may have to use sendkeys instead to get it to work

Comment: It is definitely IE8 - I just tested with 8 and get the same error that you get. Are you not able to upgrade to IE9 at work?